# Why does hidden not work for dash_html_components.Label?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

When I try to hide a `dash_html_components.Label` with hidden, like this:

```
app.layout = html.Label('test',hidden=True)
```

I can still see the `Label`. But when I replace `Label` with `Div`, it does work. What could be the reason?

They are not used in any Callbacks.
Could the `Label`'s `style` maybe overwrite it? But then, why does it behave different for the `Div`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hidden` argument seems to be broken for the Label class. You can use the style attribute to achieve the same behaviour:

```
app.layout = html.Label('test', style={"visibility": "hidden"})
```

or

```
app.layout = html.Label('test', style={"display": "none"})
```

if you want to hide the label with no place occupied on the page.